# Mathemathical model equation PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, hyperbolic-equations

I am studying models in DPE an the professor give us this problem:

> $\begin{cases}u_t+au_x=f(x,t)\\ u(x,0)=g(x)\end{cases}$

I've studied the transport equation and the Burger's equation. About heat equation, a little. Hoewever, this one is not included in those kinds of problems.

I will be very mercy if someone could help me with indications to this solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: what happens along the line $x = at + c$?

Comment: $u'(x(t),t)=u_t(x(t),t)+u_x(x(t),t)x'(t)=u_t(x(t),t)+au_x(x(t),t)=f(x,t)$...? I could not continue yet.

Comment: Have you done a Google search for a similar PDE? See https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/pracfinal1sols.pdf?

Comment: Further hint: if $v(t) = u(at+c, t)$, then $$\dfrac{dv}{dt} = a u_x(at+c,t) + u_t(at+c,t) = \ldots$$

Comment: Thank you, @Axion004.

Comment: Thank you, @RobertIsrael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find the characteristics with this system of ODE's:

$\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{dx}{a}=\dfrac{du}{f(x,t)}$

From the first proportion, $x=c_1+at$. Now:

$\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{du}{f(at+c_1,t)}$ or

$f(at+c_1,t)dt=du$ Integrating,

$$u(x,t)=\int_0^tf(ar+c_1,r)dr+c_2=\int_0^tf(ar+x-at,r)dr+c_2$$

For the general solution we have to consider $c_1$ and $c_2$ are somehow related: $c_2=h(c_1)$, with $h$ some single variable differentiable function to determine with th initial conditions: $c_2=h(x-at)$:

$$u(x,t)=\int_0^tf(ar+x-at,r)dr+h(x-at)$$

Finally we can impose the i.c. $u(x,0)=g(x)$

$u(x,0)=g(x)=h(x)$ leading to

$$u(x,t)=\int_0^tf(ar+x-at,r)dr+g(x-at)$$

**Added**
I just finished and see the link in the comments to your post. There is the answer, but it is proposed and checked, not deduced, so I post mine as it shows a way to get the solution using the method of characteristics.

$$u(x,t)=g(x-at)+\int_0^tf(x-a(t-r),r)dr$$

Comment: Thank you, I will study this.

Comment: So, this kind of proportions can always be used? This will help a lot... but I did not study this yet. I can get $\dfrac{\partial u}{f (x+y)}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{\partial t}+\frac{a}{\partial x}}$. But this I could not get those proportions. Many thanks.

Comment: You can find how to pose and why can be used to solve the PDE if you google with "method of characteristics".

Comment: Perfect, many thanks.